# Php strtotime can not get right in February

Tags: php, strtotime

Script

```
$now = date('Y-m-d');   // 2017-06-30
echo date('Y-m', strtotime(' -5 month'));  //2017-01
echo date('Y-m', strtotime(' -4 month'));  //2017-03
```

Comment: What you expect it to do, because there is no 30rd in February so it should be 1st on March. If you want to minus exact month, just give `$now = date('Y-m'); // 2017-06` (Without day)

Comment: Thanks.  It's right.

Comment: $now = date('Y-m');  echo date('Y-m', strtotime($now . ' -4 month'));